# Fallowing ESLint rules with else if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eslint

I have this code else/if code

```
       if (_.has($scope.item, 'comment_id')) {
          track(one);
        } else if (_.has($scope.item, 'post_id')) {
          track(two);
        } else {
          if ($scope.followers) {
            track(three);
          } else {
            track(four);
          }
        }
```

but ESlint want's me to turn it into this

```
        if (_.has($scope.item, 'comment_id')) {
          track(one);
        } else if (_.has($scope.item, 'post_id')) {
          track(two);
        } else if ($scope.followers) {
          track(three);
        } else {
          track(four);
        }
```

Are they the same thing?

Comment: Yes, why would they be different? You only fall into the outer `else` if the others fail. Same as chaining another `else/if`.

Comment: `else` + `if` is literally an `else if`. `else` + `else` is still `else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent. ESLint is smart enough to detect that and hence the suggestion. The reason is that you only really have four alternatives in the `if/else` construct - when the code doesn't match any of the first two conditions, it will always execute the outer

```
else {
  if ($scope.followers) {
    track(three);
  } else {
    track(four);
  }
}
```

And that will only ever result in one of two things happening. Extracting the `if ($scope.followers)` as an `else if` follows the exact same logic path.

This can be demonstrated very easily by abstracting away the conditions and generating a truth table, then checking the results. It can be done on paper but since you already have the code, it's also easy to make it as code:

```js
function nested(a, b, c) {
  if (a) {
    return "track(one)";
  } else if (b) {
    return "track(two)";
  } else {
    if (c) {
      return "track(three)";
    } else {
      return "track(four)";
    }
  }
}

function chained(a, b, c) {
  if (a) {
    return "track(one)";
  } else if (b) {
    return "track(two)";
  } else if (c) {
    return "track(three)";
  } else {
    return "track(four)";
  }
}

const truthTable = [
  [false, false, false],
  [false, false, true ],
  [false, true , false],
  [false, true , true ],
  [true , false, false],
  [true , false, true ],
  [true , true , false],
  [true , true , true ],
];

for(const [a, b, c] of truthTable) {
  const nestedResult = nested(a, b, c);
  console.log(`called nested() with 
  a=${a}
  b=${b}
  c=${c}
  result: ${nestedResult}`);
  
  const chainedResult = chained(a, b, c);
  console.log(`called nested() with 
  a=${a}
  b=${b}
  c=${c}
  result: ${chainedResult}`);
  
  console.log(`matching results?: ${nestedResult === chainedResult}`);
  
  console.log(`------------------------`);
}
```

Alternatively, you can generate an actual truth table to visualise the results:

```js
function nested(a, b, c) {
  if (a) {
    return "track(one)";
  } else if (b) {
    return "track(two)";
  } else {
    if (c) {
      return "track(three)";
    } else {
      return "track(four)";
    }
  }
}

function chained(a, b, c) {
  if (a) {
    return "track(one)";
  } else if (b) {
    return "track(two)";
  } else if (c) {
    return "track(three)";
  } else {
    return "track(four)";
  }
}

const truthTable = [
  [false, false, false],
  [false, false, true ],
  [false, true , false],
  [false, true , true ],
  [true , false, false],
  [true , false, true ],
  [true , true , false],
  [true , true , true ],
];

const enrich = truthTable
  .map(row => row.concat(nested(...row), chained(...row))) //add the results of the two calls
  .map(row => row.concat(row[row.length-1] === row[row.length-2])) //compare the last two

const table = document.querySelector("table");
for (const rowData of enrich) {
  const newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (const rowValue of rowData) {
    const cell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    cell.textContent = rowValue;
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
    <th>c</th>
    <th>nested result</th>
    <th>chained result</th>
    <th>results equal</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```